# How do I use Xcode12 keyboardShortcut(_:)?

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode12

I found out that "keyboardShortcut(_:)" was released in the new Xcode12, and I thought I could get events by typing them with the keyboard, but I don't know how to use it.

I'm sorry, but I'd like to hear more about how to use it with examples.

Thank you in advance for your help.

**editing1.............**
I found out that I can use keyboardShortcut to make the button action.

MYCODE

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("button"){
            print("push_A")
        }
        .keyboardShortcut("a",modifiers: .option)
    }
}
```

Do I have to place a myriad of buttons in order to use keybordShortcut?

Comment: Did you get this to work? The keyboard shortcut seems to only be called once. After that it does not work for me.